# Homepage should be customized for each user

Tags: discussion, status-completed, homepage

I think, every account holder should have the facility to format the homepage as per his requirement. Account Holder can put the condition regarding what type of questions he/she want to me shown on his/her home-screen (in the sense of particular tags). However, I know that anyone can find tag related questions, but this is for simplicity. We can also add some extra features on the homepage as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is already true, see

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/

It is just transparent to you. Select favorite tags and the homepage will adapt to that.